# 'bridges' on a PCB copper layer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I've come across a design where each pad was connected using 4 'bridges' to the GND copper layar. What stands behind these 'bridges'? Why not make a full copper layer with only solder-mask defining the pads?

[image]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No, they are not bridges, they are pads with [thermal relief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_relief).

> A typical pad on a printed circuit board is only connected to a few narrow tracks. A pad directly connected to the copper pour is difficult to solder since the heat quickly leaks away from the pad into the copper pour due to high thermal conductivity of copper. A thermal connection restricts the heat flow, making the pad easier to solder.

Comment: I agree, they are "thermal conductors," designed/intended to remove heat away from the socket.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that sometimes you don't want thermal relief. One example is small SMT connectors. Those are all too easy to tear off the PCB if you're using thermals. Another is (perhaps obviously!) power components. You WANT to conduct the heat from the pad to the copper.

Comment: Why they don't use one thermal relief path, instead of four? Is that a matter of stability?

Comment: Actually, you can use any number of thermal relief path you want. If you want a low impedance and rigid signal path, no thermal relief is best. But there will be more heat leaks away when soldering, So, you should make a decision between the two.

Comment: BTW, but only one fat path may not 'rigid' as separating them into several narrow paths around the pad.

Answer (score 2):

The "bridge" that you called are also called the "spoke". The below image is a thermal 
pattern with 4 spokes used.

[image]

If you hand solder a through hole chip ground pin directly connected to ground plane you will 
discover a problem; soldering becomes very difficult since the soldering iron heat is all sink by the 
via and ground plane. This problem becomes more serious with heavier copper plane such as 
two once or more, obviously it’s also depend on the area of the plane.

To resolve this issue thermal pattern are used in between via barrel and the copper pour; the 
thermal pattern reduces the total width of copper connected to the copper pour, reducing the 
thermal conductivity; thus reducing the thermal sink problem.

Comment: Why do they use not just one spoke, instead of four? Or is that a matter of 'stability' ?